# Cannot create springSessionRepositoryFilter while connecting Spring Session and Redis

Tags: redis, wildfly-8, spring-session, spring-data-redis

The following is the configuration that worked for me, I have created spring-data-redis.xml and included it into applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- tag::beans[] -->
    <!--<bean class="org.springframework.session.redis.embedded.EmbeddedRedisConfiguration"/> 1-->

    <!--2-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

    <!--3-->
    <bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
p:host-name="192.168.10.78" p:port="6379"/>
    <!-- end::beans[] -->
</beans>
```

Then the following is start of my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- By default looks for applicationContext.xml -->

    <!--
- Location of the XML file that defines the root application context
- Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
-->
    <!-- tag::context-param[] -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- end::context-param[] -->

    <!-- tag::springSessionRepositoryFilter[] -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- end::springSessionRepositoryFilter[] -->
```

Bellow is the problem I had previously....

I want to use Redis for sessions on Wildfly, we are using Spring Security and therefore I am trying to replace Http sessions with Spring sessions. I was following manual on this link:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/security.html
and after I resolved all dependencies, stuck with the exception bellow.
Both configuration, via XML or Java end up with the same error. Any idea?

```
[Server:nis] 14:31:21,489 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:742) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:463) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
[Server:nis]    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
[Server:nis]    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
[Server:nis]    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
[Server:nis]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
[Server:nis]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
[Server:nis]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:806) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:734) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
[Server:nis]    ... 24 more
[Server:nis]
[Server:nis] 14:31:21,494 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
[Server:nis]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
[Server:nis]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
[Server:nis] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:222)
[Server:nis]    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
[Server:nis]    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
[Server:nis]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
[Server:nis]    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
[Server:nis]    ... 3 more
[Server:nis] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:742)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:463)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
[Server:nis]    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
[Server:nis]    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:193)
[Server:nis]    ... 7 more
[Server:nis] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:806)
[Server:nis]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:734)
[Server:nis]    ... 24 more
[Server:nis]
[Server:nis] 14:31:21,505 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "nis.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
[Server:nis]     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}"}}
[Server:nis] 14:31:21,506 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "nis.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
[Server:nis] {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
[Server:nis]     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
[Server:nis]     Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}"}}
```

Comment: How are you initializing the configuration? Can you post a sample application?

Comment: Thanks Rob. I realized that I have got dependency problems, I used versions 4.0.1.RELEASE instead 4.1.6. with this change I was able to successfully put spring security session into external Redis, with XML configuration. I also had to cleanup my web.xml based on the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples
Thank you very much for providing these samples, they were crucial for solving my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11522

spring official had confirmed this bug.

org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.isAssignableFrom, the function can not support type of generics, spring session just used inherit type of generics, as below:

```
RedisOperationsSessionRepository implements SessionRepository<RedisOperationsSessionRepository.RedisSession>
```

you can use spring framework 4.0.3 and above to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've just followed the same example for my project and it worked for me.

Have you definitely got the 3 components:

1.

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityInitializer() {
        super( <You config classes>, RedisSessionConfig.class );
    }
}
```

2.

```
public class SessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {}
```

3.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class RedisSessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final JedisConnectionFactory connection = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        connection.setHostName( "localhost" );
        connection.setPort( 6379 );
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, I used xml configuration and external redis